# Java application can not serve two requests simultaneously

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have a single java application, where clicking on a button a report is generated which is heavy(around 30 mb excel report).

Before clicking on the 'generate button', there are two text fields which determines how much data you want(item id from: and item id to:).

Now the issue is when two simultaneous requests come requiring all the data, then who pressed the button first the report generates only for him and the other user gets empty report.But if one user requires full report and other user wants some of its information say 1000 rows , then both the users get their reports full of information.

Please give me some insight about where to look into and how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into [threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Look at whatever is generating the report. Sounds like you have instance data in your servlet, but it's impossible to know, since you provide almost no information with which anyone can help.

Comment: In my application,when we click generate button in jsp,reqst process through servlet which fetches data frm database & then it goes to another servlet where the excel gets generated.My application has not used threading,it is a process based java application.Also i have seen in log that when one request(which came first)for the item list gets served,i dont see any kind of logging for the 2nd reqst(which was hit simultaneously with first reqst) but as soon as the first request almost serve the full data, then i see  the second request(which already generated empty report) is hit(in the log).

Answer (score 0):

There is a **Singleton / application wide / Servlet Context wide** stored information about the reports. It can be in the web layer, the report calling layer, or in the report generating layer. Actually both request set this data, and both report generations read this data, that's why it makes confusion.

Have a look at the structure of your application, try to figure out, where it can be. It would be useful you could describe the whole process of report generation, maybe you could realize it yourself, if you go through from the beginning.

Comment: Any improvement in this field?

Comment: I still cant get over the issue. let me explain u in more detail.My application runs on tomcat 5,with 16 gb ram. Application is written in a framework like struts.What happens, when one user clicks for the report in jsp,request goes to a servlet,from there to a model object,then runs the query,fetch data,generates excel.The issue is application/server cannot serve two request for the report concurrently.report is too big(40 mb).

Comment: We see in log,when 2user concurrently hit for the report,1 request gets submitted to the server,generates the full report,then another request hit the server,but generates blank report.The issue gets solved when we bounce the tomcat server.Can you please help me on where to look?if you need additional info please let me know. Thank you